# libSDL, CMake and Mac OS X lion 2

Tags: macos, cmake, sdl

I'm trying to compile a cmake project on my mac, but it depends on the SDL.
I have alreaday read "LibSDL, CMake and MacOSX Lion", however I couldn't solve this problem.

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.4 FATAL_ERROR)
# Give a name to the project.
project(movehead)
# This include enable you to use our CMake framework
find_package(qibuild)
find_package(SDL REQUIRED)
link_directories( /usr/local/lib )
link_libraries (
     ${SDL_LIBRARY}
     SDLmain
)
# Create an executable named movehead,
# with the source file : movehead.cpp
qi_create_bin(movehead movehead.cpp)

# Tell CMake that movehead depends on ALCOMMON.
# This will set the libraries to link movehead with,
# the include paths, and so on
qi_use_lib(movehead ALCOMMON)
```

Commandline

```
 sudo qibuild make -c naoqi-sdk movehead Active configuration: naoqi-sdk (Debug)
    Building movehead in naoqi-sdk (Debug)
    Scanning dependencies of target movehead
    Linking CXX executable sdk/bin/movehead
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libSDLmain.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libSDL.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_main", referenced from:
          start in crt1.10.6.o
         (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)
      "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
          _SDL_main in movehead.cpp.o
      "_SDL_NumJoysticks", referenced from:
          _SDL_main in movehead.cpp.o
      "_SDL_JoystickEventState", referenced from:
          _SDL_main in movehead.cpp.o
      "_SDL_JoystickOpen", referenced from:
          _SDL_main in movehead.cpp.o
      "_SDL_JoystickName", referenced from:
          _SDL_main in movehead.cpp.o
      "_SDL_JoystickNumAxes", referenced from:
          _SDL_main in movehead.cpp.o
      "_SDL_PollEvent", referenced from:
          _SDL_main in movehead.cpp.o
      "_SDL_JoystickGetButton", referenced from:
          _SDL_main in movehead.cpp.o
      "_SDL_JoystickGetAxis", referenced from:
          _SDL_main in movehead.cpp.o
      "_SDL_QuitSubSystem", referenced from:
          _SDL_main in movehead.cpp.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[2]: *** [sdk/bin/movehead] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/movehead.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    [ERROR]     
                Error occured when building project movehead
    dhcp47-122:movehead yukke150$ sudo qibuild configure -c naoqi-sdk movehead --disable-assembly
    usage: qibuild [-h]


lipo -info /usr/local/lib/libSDL.dylib
Non-fat file: /usr/local/lib/libSDL.dylib is architecture: x86_64
lipo -info /usr/local/lib/libSDLmain.a
input file /usr/local/lib/libSDLmain.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: /usr/local/lib/libSDLmain.a is architecture: x86_64
```

I think these file are x86_64.
How to fix?

Comment: And I can complie "g++ main.cpp -g `sdl-config --cflags` `sdl-config --libs`", however, I cannnot complie CMake

Answer (score 1):

Use the framework distribution of SDL (provided on SDL website) work for me to compile in either x86 or x86_64.
Previously I installed it from brew, so if same (or Mac Port, etc) don't forget to uninstall those first.